# Oracle Statement doesn't work when put in a procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, ora-00933, pls-00103

I am new to Oracle and experiencing this problem.

I created a procedure like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE getArt 
as
begin
    select ar.artTitle, ar.artContent, ar.DateCreated, ar.artCategory, ac.accName 
      from hng_art ar 
           join HNG_ACCOUNTS ac 
             on ar.accNo = ac.accNo 
     order by ar.artNo desc
end getArt;
```

I tried to run the SELECT statement independently and it worked. However, when I put it in a procedure. I didn't work;
Here are the errors:

Errors for "GETART"

```
ERROR at line 4: PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
ERROR at line 4: PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
ERROR at line 5: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:     ;
```

thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Several errors.

At the moment, the compiler is objecting to the fact that you are missing a semicolon after your `select` statement.  Every statement in PL/SQL needs to be terminated with a semicolon.

Once you fix that, you'll get an error because a stored procedure cannot simply execute a `select` statement.  It has to do something with the results.  If you know that your query will always return exactly one row, you could declare some local variables and do a `select into` to populate those variables.  I'm guessing, however, that your query might return more than 1 row.  You could write a `for` loop in your procedure, iterate through the results, and do something with the rows.  Or you could declare your procedure to have an `OUT` parameter of type `SYS_REFCURSOR`, open a cursor for your query, and return that cursor to the caller.  If you're on 12.1 or later, Oracle has introduced a bit of syntactic sugar so that a procedure can return a result without declaring such an `OUT` parameter but I'm guessing that's probably not the situation you're in.

Syntactically, you could do something like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE getArt( p_rc OUT sys_refcursor )
as
begin
  open p_rc
   for  
    select ar.artTitle, ar.artContent, ar.DateCreated, ar.artCategory, ac.accName 
      from hng_art ar 
           join HNG_ACCOUNTS ac 
             on ar.accNo = ac.accNo 
     order by ar.artNo desc;
end getArt;
```

While that is legal, however, it is not particularly idiomatic.  If you have code that is just executing a `select` statement, it would generally make much more sense to create a view rather than a stored procedure.  If you are doing a large amount of PL/SQL processing of the results before returning them, a pipelined table function might make sense.

Comment: I switched View and that worked for me. thank you for your advice, I'll study more.